# Where to see the detail of do_rootfs procedure[the copied files path] in OpenEmbeded/yocto?

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

The yocto project using the OpenEmbeded to build the projects. I have a recipes containing some dynamic libraries. When the do_rootfs process, it will copy the libraries to the rootfs directory and pack it to be a tar.bz2 ball. But the dynamic library file in generated tarball is not same as the recipes input. I use the `bitbake -v core-image-minimal` to see the detail how it copy files. But it just give a simple hint: `libEGL.so->libEGL.so`, it just tell me the file name, **I want to know the source file directory path**. So where's the source file directory path?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Please read at least a [quick start documentation](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html) to see the big picture of the whole process. All regular software built from recipes becomes packaged into ipk (or deb, or rpm) packages first and the image generation process operates with that packages, so it's not straight copying from somewhere.

The packages are stored in feeds located in the [`build/tmp/deploy/ipk`](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#structure-build-tmp-deploy-ipk) (or deb, or rpm) folder. You can examine them with standard tools (like ar and tar for ipk and deb, or rpm2cpio with friends for rpm).

The package contents comes from `packages-split` directory of package work directory, like mentioned in [`build/tmp/work` description](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#structure-build-tmp-work). That, in turn, comes from `packages` directory of the same work directory. Which, in its turn, comes from `image` directory (which is the default for [`D` variable](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-D)), and `image` directory has all the files that are installed (as in [do_install](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-tasks-install)) by the recipe. Of course, all of these directories are made with different purposes in mind, so it's not just copying from one place to another, things done in-between are described in a [nice comment in the `package.bbclass`](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/package.bbclass) file.

Also of interest in this case might be the do_rootfs task log, which, [as usually](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging-viewing-logs-from-failed-tasks), is stored in the `${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_rootfs`